# jquery fatching data issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

guys i m facing some issue in jquery fatching data from ajax .. php file respond proper and send data in json formate in jquery file alert box also confirming me data proper fatch from php file but when i have to show data in html file they didn't shown .. guys guide me what mistake i was done in script..

html:

```
<tr>                    
    <td colspan="6">
        <table border="1" width="100%" align="center" class="info">
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

jquery :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "billingprocess.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
        for (var x = 0; x < msg.length; x++) {
            var div = $("<tr>").appendTo(".info");
            $("<td>").addClass("cols").text(msg[x].B_account).appendTo(div);
            $("<td>").addClass("cols").text(msg[x].B_consumer).appendTo(div);
            $("<td>").addClass("cols").text(msg[x].month).appendTo(div);
            $("<td>").addClass("cols").text(msg[x].net_amount).appendTo(div);
            $("<td>").addClass("cols").text(msg[x].due_date).appendTo(div);
            $("<td>").addClass("cols").text(msg[x].gross_amount).appendTo(div);
        }
    }
});
```

php code:

```
if ($rc > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $rc) {
        $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($squery);
        $temp[$i] = array("B_account" = > $r['B_account'],
                          "B_consumer" = > $r['B_consumer'],
                          "month" = > $r['month']."-".$r['year'],
                          "net_amount" = > $r['net_amount'],
                          "due_date" = > $r['due_date']."-".$r['month']."-".$r['year'],
                          "gross_amount" = > $r['gross_amount']);
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($temp);
}
```

JSON format return data :

```
[
    {
        "B_account": "1014052480080",
        "B_consumer": "LA712722",
        "month": "Nov-11",
        "net_amount": "2107",
        "due_date": "30-Nov-11",
        "gross_amount": "2282"
    },
    {
        "B_account": "1014052480080",
        "B_consumer": "LA712722",
        "month": "Dec-11",
        "net_amount": "1217",
        "due_date": "30-Dec-11",
        "gross_amount": "1316"
    },
    {
        "B_account": "1014052480080",
        "B_consumer": "LA712722",
        "month": "Jan-12",
        "net_amount": "737",
        "due_date": "31-Jan-12",
        "gross_amount": "795"
    }
]
```

this is my whole code I think error within script, but anyone solved this problem?

Comment: Can you post your JSON? Try adding `dataType: json` to your Ajax request.

Comment: try using `while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($squery)){ $temp[]=...`. Inspect the AJAX request in browser console to see what is sent and returned and that they are what you expect

Comment: @undefined pls check code again .. i m update json also

Comment: @charlietfl pls check code .. php file return data as per my requirment but i think the problem in display in html .

Comment: what does `console.log(msg)` give you? you seem to have forgotten to set  `dataType:"json"`, in which case you are getting a string, not with an object

Comment: Best to set `dataType:'json'` in ajax options

Comment: If it's JSON, it's probably a string, yet you seem to be treating it like an object without doing any parsing? And if it's an object, it has no length, that would be an array, which it is probably not!

Comment: thnks guys problem solved .. issue in datatype:'json'

Answer (score 1):

In your `success` callback you have

```
success: function(msg) { // msg is json string here
    for (var x = 0; x < msg.length; x++) {...}
}
```

but before you iterate it you should convert the returned data to an `object` because you have only the `json` string and there was no `dataType` defined so it could be gained using `$.parseJSON`

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(msg);
```

then replace following

```
for (var x = 0; x < msg.length; x++) {...}
```

with

```
$.each(obj, function(k, v){
    // here k is key and v is the value, for example try following
    console.log(obj[k]);
    console.log(k);
    console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: don't need to call `$.parseJSON(msg);` when set `dataType:'json`...jQuery will do it for you

Comment: @charlietfl, yes but there was no data type in his example.

Comment: understood...just clarifying

Comment: @GreatOne, when you don't have a data type defined you can use `$.parseJSON(msg);` to convert the returned `json` string to an `obect`.

Comment: in OP case `$.getJSON` would be ideal

Comment: @charlietfl, I think so, just tried to answer in the way `OP` already did it.

Comment: thanks both of you guyz i m really appreciate both of expert . @SheikhHeera